# Can't deploy MVC application to IIS - Is my web.config file to blame

Tags: asp.net, iis, model-view-controller, web-config

I'm struggling to deploy any MVC application onto IIS in a windows 10 environment.

I always get an HTTP error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid. It goes on to suggest there is a problem reading the configuration file.

On a similar post on this site it was suggested that asp.net was not installed but I'm certain that I've done it. I've used the Aspnet_regiis.exe tool and followed the instruction on the link below.
http://www.jammer.biz/enable-asp-net-on-windows-10/

The webconfig file as it came out of visual studio 2017 when I published is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\HelloWorld.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: e88818e3-e6fd-4105-94cc-5be77ed93582-->
```

I've not edited it since none of the tutorials I've followed it tell me to.
I've made sure that full access rights on the folder are granted.

[Here is the error message as seen from in IIS.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8jA1.png)
Why is IIS struggling to read my config file?

Thanks in advance.

Ian

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue when trying to publish a .NetCore2.0 mvc app. The solution can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/index?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x

In my case, I did not have the .NET Core Hosting Bundle installed.